# subtraction of signed 2's complement numbers

Tags: hardware-failure

Consider we use 3-bit two's complement number and we are going to perform subtraction operation. the minuend is +3 and the subtrahend is -4. we should get 2's complement of subtrahend and add it to minuend. 
+3=011
-4=100--->it's two's complement is again 100
now we add them and get 111 which is incorrect. because we should get 3-(-4)=+7 but the result is negative! how you analysis overflow? why result is wrong?

Comment: If  you are using the left most bit to indicate sign then you cannot use the whole 3-bit number. 100 is *either* 4 or it is in fact (negative) 0.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: We know that a one way we can detect overflow is to XOR the input carry to the MSB with output carry from MSB. When we use 3_bit number the range is -4<=N<=+3. The rule for performing subtraction is to get 2's complement of subtrahend and then add it to the minuend. If A=+3 and B=-4 and perform A-B the result would be "111" in binary and there is no any carry. therefore XORing carries will result in '0'. That means there is no any overflow. But we know that result is incorrect because +3-(-4)=+7 that can not be shown with 3_bit number. Why hardware cannot detect this overflow?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the left most bit to indicate sign then you cannot use the whole 3-bit number. `100` is either (positive, unsigned) 4 or it is in fact (negative) 0.

For your number to be "-4" then it must actually be `1100` and not just `100`. You then work with the information you have, knowing that you have a 3 bit number and that one of those number is negative.

What I mean is the value you are getting *is* 7. `111` is, for 3 bit unsigned numbers, exactly 7.

You are just not taking account of the fact that the first digit is not your sign digit if you are using 3-bit complement function. You have to look at your number first and discard information that is not relevant to the immediate operation, i.e. the sign digit. The sign tells you what you need to do with it, but it is not a "real" part of the value of that number.

If you are using a 3-bit number with sign, then by definition you can only perform 2-bit addition and subtraction.

Comment: I think you mean signed-magnitude solution for subtraction that deals with sign bit separately. But I mean subtraction in 2's complement numbers based on "Computer Architecture" book written by Morris Mano

Comment: I do not have access to that book. If you are quoting from or using some source information then you need to edit your question to clarify the context.